# Vertical space constraint strange behavior

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, constraints, ios-autolayout

I am trying to implement `UIScrollView` from `Storyboard` using `Interface Builder`. The `ViewController` im working on have `UINavigationBar`.
 This is the steps i perform within my `Storyboard`

1. adding `UIScrollView` and set the top, bottom, left, right spacing to 0 (not to margins).
2. add `UIView` and set it to be a child of the scrollView. set its spacing to: top, left, right to 0 and it width and hight to the value listed, also set spacing to bottom of the viewcontroller.

[image]

The strange behavior is that the top constraint get way high than expected,
What am i missing here?
Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried to enable the Leading, Trailing and Top Edges to the Superviews(UIScrollView) and set the height?

Comment: When using scrollsViews, always add a contentView as a subView and then any subsequent views go inside this contentView. Give the contentView a leading, top, trailing and bottom to its superView. Set equal widths and heights to that of your wholeView. Depending on the direction of the scroll, set equal width/height to have a lower priority. This contentView will resize the scrollView's scroll size depending on the constraints of the contentView's subviews.

Comment: @Rikh same thing happens, the view i added now "contentView" is shifted down 64 points

Comment: @Rikh Yes i am.

Comment: Sorry i deleted my comment, apparently xcode 8 requires you to uncheck scroll view insets and in xcode 7 it works without it as far as i recall atleast. Try the answer i posted. (Had to upload screenshot)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well what you can do is select your view controller from the heirarchy on the left and in the attributes inspector uncheck "adjust scroll view insets".

[image]